# Velocity js ui pack animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am building an educational resource site with a page which shows grades , results and statistics.

I am using velocity js for animations when the user clicks it fades out the data downward the fades it in upward, but before the animation occurs the data is appended with styled divs (using jquery .append() method) to the code is like

$('#dataTarget').velocity("transition.slideDownOut",1000);// slideout animation
document.getElementById("dataTarget").innerHTML = "";//empties display div

/* loops and stuff processing on an object with excercise names and scores*/

$('#dataTarget').velocity("transition.slideUpIn",1000);//animates the divs contents in to sight

The two animations happen after the data is appended does stagger or delay help i tried both no great change the flash showing change occurs then the two animations.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity js has begin and complete callbacks, i had to put a lot of my logic in these functions but it worked as i wanted,